# xsd empty string validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Based on that xsd schema:

```
<xs:simpleType name="TextType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
...
<xs:element maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="0" name="MyText" type="TextType"/>
```

should empty space values like this be valid or not and why?

```
<MyText>  </MyText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. The value can be any string between 1-50 characters in length, and this is a string whose length is between those limits.

If you want to eliminate whitespace before applying the length checks, you could consider using the `xs:whiteSpace` facet, or using a derived type such as `xs:token`.

Comment: Ok I get it. It has to do with the fact that `This string datatype is the only predefined datatype for which no whitespace replacement is performed`  [link](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch04_03.htm) ?

Comment: When using the .Net XMLReader, the schema validation is failing for this scenario. Based on what you are saying, the schema validation should pass, correct?

Comment: Yes, it should. But there are many details where the Microsoft XSD implementation isn't very conformant to the W3C spec.